# How to install CDT to Eclipse Luna

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am trying to install the C/C++ development tools for Eclipse Luna.

Taking reference from this page [here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php), I navigated to Help> Install New Software> and placed `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4`
in the "Works with" section.

I got the options for C/C++ Development Tools and C/C++ Development Tools SDK which I downloaded and restarted Eclipse. However, on restarting eclipse I cannot find any place/interface to create C programs or files. The tools are showing up in the installed softwares list(screen attached).

I have also installed MinGw as instructed [here](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Cygwin_HowTo.html#mingw).

Have I missed any step? How can I start C development in Luna. Please advice.[image]

Comment: Why not downloading the C/C++ packaged version of eclipse directly? You can find the download link here
http://eclipse.org/downloads/ Look for "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers"

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: @MM for Luna... No!!! I had a Kepler (standard not EE) present in my system and the process mentioned above worked for it. I have no idea why it failed for the Luna version.

Comment: Hello, have you solved your problem? If yes could you please share the solution :)

Comment: @Enissay no, I haven't found a solution for Luna EE, however the same steps mentioned above worked for Kepler SE

Comment: With mars, use `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.7`

Comment: Luna (L) is a past version, install Eclipse Neon (N) now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Luna.  I installed Java 1.7.0_80, which then allowed me to change to the C/C++ Perspective and create new C/C++ projects.

My system previously only had Java 1.6.0_45, which was sufficient to run Luna but apparently insufficient to run CDT in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

Your JDK version is below 1.6 which is too old. You should upgrade it to 1.7 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - installing java 8 helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, using Luna SR 1a on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Switching from Java 1.6.0_34 to 1.7.0_75 fixed the issue - everything works now